# What is the paper "Oliver [1993]" describing a PHP algorithm to calculate text similarity?

Tags: php, string, text, similarity

There is a function similar_text() in the PHP library.  The documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) tells me that "This calculates the similarity between two strings as described in Oliver [1993]."

Despite extensive searching, I can't find the paper that "Oliver [1993]" is referring to; nor any candidate for who "Oliver" might be.  The PHP source is undocumented.  The only other reference to Oliver 1993 is in a forum at http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=41089, and I think that information is derived from the PHP documentation.

Anyone aware of what this might be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or this?

> Programming Classics: Implementing the World's Best Algorithms (Hardback)
>   By (author) Ian Oliver
>
> **Publisher:** Pearson Education
>   **Published:** 01 April 1994
>   **ISBN 13:** 9780131004139
>   **ISBN 10:** 013100413

http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/book/9780131004139/Programming-Classics

yes this should be it...

http://books.google.hu/books?id=e7D-mITABmEC&pg=PT501&lpg=PT501&dq=%22ian+oliver%22+%22programming+classics%22+similar_text&source=bl&ots=oavkzNrqVv&sig=1SY1by3i68vvjwo3J-suMv29Af0&hl=hu&ei=jGMfTPKUGN-XOMbWrfsL&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22ian%20oliver%22%20%22programming%20classics%22%20similar_text&f=false

Comment: I agree. It's §7.2 (p. 188) of [Oliver's book](http://books.google.com/books?cd=1&id=_oFQAAAAMAAJ&dq=0131004131&q=same+or+similar#search_anchor).

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED:

http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=124336339205964&w=2 suggests that the link is http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.52.1476

```
Decision Graphs - An Extension of Decision Trees (1993) by Jonathan J. Oliver
```

Comment: That's a little more plausible, but skimming through it, there's no clear application to string similarity..

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking

> *Decision Graphs - An Extension of Decision Trees*
>   Jonathan J. Oliver
>
> Department of Computer Science
>   Monash University
>   Clayton, Victoria, Australia

http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg42231.html, there is a link which gives you an old link to the document here: 
http://web.archive.org/web/19970527103907/http://www.cs.monash.edu.au/~jono/TechReports/TR173.dgraph.ps