# Searching Array for similar spelled words/objects

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am looking for a solution similar to Google's "Did You Mean: *Word*"

I have an array of vehicles entered as

```
2011ChevroletMalibu
2011FordF150
2009FordProbe
etc...
```

In my app I have three Textfields.

`Year Make Model` .

When the user types in 2011 Chevrolet Malabu  (notice that Malibu is misspelled) and hits search...
Id like to reply "Did you mean: 2011 Chevrolet Malibu". 
Anyone have any suggestions on how to "search for similar"? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK that is not any function the iOS SDK would solve for you - however, there are many algorithms available doing just that.

Look out for:

[Phonetic Soundex String Comparison](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/phonetic-string-comparison-with-soundex)

[Levenshtein Distance](http://www.merriampark.com/ld.htm)

[Oliver 1993](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084608/what-is-the-paper-oliver-1993-describing-a-php-algorithm-to-calculate-text-s)

Answer (score 1):

Louie, I think it is not very simple. You need use some phonetic search. If your app use data provided by a webservice and you have a mssqlserver>=2000 behind this webservice, you can use SOUNDEX function in your searchs. But if you want, implement your own phonetic search, it is a big challenge.

Comment: It really is not THAT hard to implement a soundex comparison. And if you need it remotely, a one-liner in PHP would do.

Answer (score 0):

Look at soundx "hashes" or if you have the CPU for it the levenshtein distance.   Soundx will be cheaper to compute, the levenshtein distance will give better results.