# similar_text in php source code

Tags: php, c, string, text-search

I'm trying to use th function similar_text in PHP in my application written in C, I tried googling and downloaded the source but can't I find it. Any one knows where to find the C implementation of the function in php source code? I'm thinking of using using it instead of building my own one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136349/how-does-similar-text-work gives an extremely thorough discussion of the subject. It even contains the source in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start to have a look at:

```
ext/standard/string.c line: 2999
```

This is for php 5.4.10.

You can find this out for yourself using:

```
grep -r 'similar_text' PHP_SOURCE_FOLDER
```