# Laravel: Trying a way to check if street address is same as other user

Tags: php, laravel

I am filling in for a backend developer and building out a referral program.  I have a `$user->street_address` and a `$referrer->street_address`.  I am trying to check if these two match or are similar to avoid users referring themself.  I come from a javascript background ... is regex the best way to handle this?

Comment: "Match" is pretty easy, just `$user->street_address == $referrer->street_address`. "Similar" is a giant can of worms; depending on what `street_address` contains, case sensitivity, spaces, etc.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520646/how-to-check-a-partial-similarity-of-two-strings-in-php